Why is the thing-in-itself ideal in Schelling's philosophy
In System of Transcendental idealism P68

what the ideal activity becomes fixated as? So far as it is fixated at all, it ceases to be pure activity. It becomes in the same action
opposed to the activity confined within the limit, and is thus apprehended as an activity fixated but set in opposition to the real self. So far as it is apprehended as fixated, it acquires an ideal substrate; so far as it is apprehended as an activity opposed to the real self, it itself becomes—but only in this opposition—a real activity; it becomes the activity of something really opposed to the real self. But this real opponent to the real self is nothing other than the thing-in-itself.
Thus the ideal activity, having passed the limit and now become
an object, at this point disappears as such from consciousness and is
transformed into the thing-in-itself.

Shouldn't the self-in-itself be ideal. And thing-in-itself is intuited through the self.
